# Inserting into mysql database not working from php

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am having trouble inserting into my database. One of my insert statements works because when I do a Select * from table; i get the new records. However the other table that I want to be inserted doesnt have any values when I select * from it.

The DDL of the 2 tables that I want the values inserted are

```
CREATE TABLE Job(uid INTEGER,job_id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
input varchar(500),status varchar(100),start_time time,finish_time time,
FOREIGN KEY(uid) REFERENCES User(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE,
PRIMARY KEY(job_id))ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE BLAST(database varchar(100),evalue varchar(100),job_id INTEGER, 
FOREIGN KEY (job_id) REFERENCES Job(job_id))ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The table that has issues is the BLAST Table. I believe it is because there is a foreign key of job_id and I dont actually insert that value in. I thought it would just do the same job_id as the job_id in the Job table but I guess im wrong. If someone could explain to me what to do I would greatly appreciate it!

PHP code

```
<select id="database" name="database">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Database</option>
    <option value="Archaea">Archaea</option>
    <option value="Bacteria">Bacteria</option>
</select>

<select id="evalue" name="evalue">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled"> evalue <option>
    <option value="0.0001">0.0001</option>
    <option value="0.001">0.001</option>
</select>

<select id="hits" name="hits">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled"> Hits</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
</select>

<input id="BlastSearch" type="text" name="BlastSearch" value='' />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
<button type="reset" value="Clear">Clear</button>
</form>
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once '../secure/database.php';
    $mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
    }

    //Insert the values into the database

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

            //declare variables to what the user defines them as
            $db = $_POST['database'];
            $evalue = $_POST['evalue'];
            $sequence = $_POST['BlastSearch'];

            //insert the values into the database
            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `Job` (`uid`, `input`, `status`, `start_time`, `finish_time`) VALUES ('1', '" . $sequence . "', 'running' , NOW(), NOW())");

            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `BLAST`(`database`, `evalue`, `job_id`) VALUES ('" . $db . "','" . $evalue . "', '1')") or die(mysqli_error($db));



    }
  ?>
```

ERROR I AM GETTING: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''job_id',`database`, `evalue`) VALUES ('56','0.001', 'Eukaryota')' at line 1

Comment: not when i do php search.php :(

Comment: I'm *pretty sure* that second query is going to result in an error.  Since you have a string literal as a column name and then back-ticked identifier called "1" in the values.

Comment: That was just me being dumb sorry. I changed them back and it still doesnt work :(

Answer (score 3):

```
if($mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `BLAST`(`database`, `evalue`, `job_id`) VALUES ('" . $db . "','" . $evalue . "', '".$mysqli->insert_id."')")) {
  echo "Error description: " . mysqli_error($mysqli);
}
```

1) Change hard coded '1' to use `$mysqli->insert_id`. You need to insert the proper job_id that is being generated by your first query:

See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

2) Change back ticks to single quotes in wrapper of **job_id** value:
Change: **`".$mysqli->insert_id."`** to **' ".$mysqli->insert_id." '**. Notice we are changing the back ticks wrapper to a single quote wrapper.

3) Pass in correct variable to the `mysqli_error($mysqli)` function. Pass in **$mysqli** instead of **$db**.

4) Change the `job_id` wrapper in your insert query to use back ticks, not single quotes.

Comment: So i just add $mysqli->insert_id after?

Comment: Add `$mysqli->insert_id` in place of the hard coded '1' you have in the second query. Also, you need to change the back ticks to apostrophes that you are wrapping the query value in. (See example above.)

Comment: it still tells me empty set :(

Comment: It tells you that on what? Post the **SELECT** query you are trying to run that gives you no results.

Comment: Im about to drop out of college and change career paths because I cant figure this out

Comment: So it's a problem with the insert query still... you also need to change the variable being passed into: `mysqli_error()`. It needs to pass in the connection variable, so instead of passing in $db, pass in `$mysqli`. Answer above edited to reflect this. If you are still having problems with the INSERT query, then show us the error message that `mysqli_error()` outputs.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''job_id',`database`, `evalue`) VALUES ('56','0.001', 'Eukaryota')' at line 1

Comment: You are trying to insert a STRING into an INTEGER field. `job_id` column is expecting an Integer, but you are passing in a string: **Eukaryota**. Either change the column type of `job_id` in your database schema, or change the job_id value being saved from a string to an integer.

Comment: I see the error of database and evalue switched. I fixed that and I Still get that error

Comment: I get this error now.... You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''job_id',`database`, `evalue`) VALUES ('57','Eukaryota', '0.001')' at line 1

Comment: its it supposed to be 'job_id' or `job_id` ?

Comment: Now you are trying to save a FLOAT into an INTEGER field. An integer needs to be a whole number. A decimal number is a FLOAT.

Comment: job_id should be wrapped in back ticks, not single quotes. `\`job_id\``

Comment: First off I appreciate all your help!!! After all of this I finally got a different error!!! I will update the post with my new code and the new error (it tells me database isnt a field) but it definelty is!

Comment: Alright well it is not letting me update my code for some reason but here is what I have now and the error that I am getting!  




$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `BLAST`(`database`, `evalue`, `job_id`) VALUES ('" . $db . "','" . $evalue . "', '".$mysqli->insert_id."')") or die(mysqli_error($db));


ERROR I AM GETTING: Unknown column 'database' in 'field list'

Comment: SMH MY PARTNER TOLD ME THE WRONG NAME OF A COLUMN AND WASTED 3 HOURS OF MY TIME WOW

Comment: Please mark this as the accepted answer if it was helpful to you in resolving your issue. There is a green check mark icon you can click to the left of the answer which will mark the answer as accepted. Glad to be able to help!